# Input.Touch not working on OSX

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I'm a total beginner in Unity and created a function that simply sets the text of a text element when a touch is detected like this:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (didTap ()) {
        print ("did tap!");
        tapText.text = "TAP!";
    }
}

private bool didTap() {
    print ("checking didtap");
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch initialTouch = Input.GetTouch (0);
        return initialTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I run this on an actual device (Android phone) it works perfectly, but when I 'click' in the unity editor when running the game nothing happens. I'm running OSX 10.12.2. Anything I need to configure to have the mouse mimic touch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate Unity's play mode window onto your mobile device by using the [UnityRemote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) app. This will allow you to interact with your phone's features, while still running Unity on your computer.

UnityRemote requires some setup in Unity along with downloading the app. Consider watching this video: [Unity Remote Setup Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-jYAWtVnQA)

Alternatively, see the answer from Hellium in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972962/6837889), in conjunction with getting the mouse clicks, to only compile code based on the device used.

Comment: But the game is specific for mobile devices. I want to only detect touch, but be able to trigger that touch in the unity editor. Is that possible? Or is it a matter of checking both?

Comment: In that case you can use the [UnityRemote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) app on your phone, which essentially connects your device to your computer to duplicate the play mode on your phone.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll look in to that! If you edit the answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Edited! Word to the wise - unityremote can be tricky to setup sometimes. proceed with patience!

Answer (score 0):

There's an odd difference between "touch" input and "mouse" input in Unity. `Input.touchCount` will always return 0 while you're running in the Editor but `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` works for both the Editor and *the first touch of one or more touches while on a mobile build*.

You have two options to solve this issue via code (your other option is [the remote ryemoss mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45337579/1159604)):

- If you're only ever using one touch, use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` and `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`.
- Use `#if UNITY_IOS`, `#if UNITY_ANDROID` and `#if UNITY_EDITOR` tags to write separate input readers for your platforms and then have them all call into the same functionality.